# Induction help discrete Math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A) For what natural number is this claim true?
B) Prove that your answer to (a) is correct using induction on n

I know the answer is 3 for the first one but I don't know how to do the second question.

5^n > 4^n + 3^n + 2^n

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $3$ is the smallest $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $5^n>4^n+3^n+2^n$. Checking that $5^3>4^3+3^3+2^3$ is the basis step of your proof by induction that $5^n>4^n+3^n+2^n$ for all $n\ge 3$. For the induction step itself you need to assume that $5^n>4^n+3^n+2^n$ for some $n\ge 3$ and somehow conclude from this that $5^{n+1}>4^{n+1}+3^{n+1}+2^{n+1}$.

$$\begin{align*}
5^{n+1}&=5\cdot 5^n\\
&>5\left(4^n+3^n+2^n\right)&\text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&=5\cdot4^n+5\cdot3^n+5\cdot2^n\;;
\end{align*}$$

is it always true that

$$5\cdot4^n+5\cdot3^n+5\cdot2^n\ge 4^{n+1}+3^{n+1}+2^{n+1}\;?$$